# DEBIAN SFTP change UMASK not working

Tags: debian, sftp, umask

I have a user let call him bob connecting via sftp with bob account.
using for client ftp-kr in VSCODE(osx) and server debian 9, I would like to setup a umask like for ftp service.

I tried adding `umask 022` and also tried `umask 0022` in both `/home/bob/.bashrc` and `/home/bob/.profile`

also tried `Subsystem  sftp  /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server -u 0022` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

update: if I create a folder I get 755 as expected but not with files; getting 644.

if I type `umask` I get `0022` as active umask

Comment: So what permission do you get with files?   Also, what client are you using? Some clients will attempt to set the permissions.  Also, did you restart sshd after changing the sshd_config?

Comment: using `ftp-kr` in `VSCode` and getting permissions `511` atm. I did restart sshd + reboot

Comment: Getting `511` is weird.  I am not sure how that would happen.

Comment: even if I sftp with root I get 511

Comment: So if you connect with winscp, filezilla, or some other sftp client  and you create new folder and new empty file what permissions do you get on each?  A umask of `022` should result in direcotory files of 0755/0644.  If you are getting 0511, something weird is going on.

Comment: actually I got confused (updated question) Im getting 644, not 511, sorry my bad!! Does that change anything ? If I ssh and create a file with any account including root I also get 644

Comment: Permissions of `644` is what you should get for a regular file and umask `022`.